# Translation-rotation: SVG not rotating around center even though translated:

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, rotation, translate-animation

I have a SVG group in my drawing called y621 with the following data:

```
$('#y621')[0].getBBox()
SVGRect {height: 10.6065673828125, width: 10.60662841796875, y: 1088.701171875, x: 890.8260498046875}
```

y621 consists of a line with a circle/path on its center:

```
<g
   id="y621"
   inkscape:label="#g6834">
  <path
     inkscape:label="#path4497"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="cc"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     id="y6"
     d="m 890.82605,1088.7012 10.6066,10.6066"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
  <path
     transform="translate(400.00435,674.62953)"
     d="m 496.25,418.625 a 0.75,0.75 0 1 1 -1.5,0 0.75,0.75 0 1 1 1.5,0 z"
     sodipodi:ry="0.75"
     sodipodi:rx="0.75"
     sodipodi:cy="418.625"
     sodipodi:cx="495.5"
     id="path4499"
     style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0"
     sodipodi:type="arc" />
</g>
```

I want to rotate it around its center. However i cant get it right. It just flys allower the place. I am using the [Jquery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html):

```
$('#y621').animate({svgTransform:'rotate(360, 891,1088)'},1000);
```

Can anybody show me what I am doing wrong? See fiddle for testing

http://jsfiddle.net/devdavid/4FC96/3/

Comment: Haven't got a solution, but I suspect it may be related to combined transforms and the coordinate space getting moved, along with the relative path points. I'm not sure if the animation overwrites previous transforms on that object, so its probably worth trying to figure out the transforms that are happening at each step before and after the animation. Hopefully someone else will be able to help who is better at combined transforms.

Answer (score 0):

getBBox returns the bounding box for elements using their 'native' values, i.e. **before** any tranformations were applied. To rotate your `<g>`, the ideal approach would be to first process elements within your `<g>` container that have been transformed, and return their screen values.
 I have a few Javascripts that I find I use quite often for svg elements to return them to their screen points. Give them a try and see if they help.

```
//----use your SVG root(svg as below) to hold svg point---
function screenLine(line,svg)
{
    var sCTM = line.getCTM()
    var x1=parseFloat(line.getAttribute("x1"))
    var y1=parseFloat(line.getAttribute("y1"))
    var x2=parseFloat(line.getAttribute("x2"))
    var y2=parseFloat(line.getAttribute("y2"))

    var mySVGPoint1 = svg.createSVGPoint();
    mySVGPoint1.x = x1
    mySVGPoint1.y = y1
    mySVGPointTrans1 = mySVGPoint1.matrixTransform(sCTM)
    line.setAttribute("x1",mySVGPointTrans1.x)
    line.setAttribute("y1",mySVGPointTrans1.y)

    var mySVGPoint2 = svg.createSVGPoint();
    mySVGPoint2.x = x2
    mySVGPoint2.y = y2
    mySVGPointTrans2= mySVGPoint2.matrixTransform(sCTM)
    line.setAttribute("x2",mySVGPointTrans2.x)
    line.setAttribute("y2",mySVGPointTrans2.y)
    //---force removal of transform--
    line.setAttribute("transform","")
    line.removeAttribute("transform")
}
function screenCircle(circle,svg)
{
    var sCTM = circle.getCTM()
    var scaleX  = sCTM.a;

    var cx=parseFloat(circle.getAttribute("cx"))
    var cy=parseFloat(circle.getAttribute("cy"))

    var r=parseFloat(circle.getAttribute("r"))

    var mySVGPointC = svg.createSVGPoint();
    mySVGPointC.x = cx
    mySVGPointC.y = cy
    mySVGPointTransC = mySVGPointC.matrixTransform(sCTM)
    circle.setAttribute("cx",mySVGPointTransC.x)
    circle.setAttribute("cy",mySVGPointTransC.y)

    circle.setAttribute("r",r*scaleX)
    //---force removal of transform--
    circle.setAttribute("transform","")
    circle.removeAttribute("transform")
}
function screenEllipse(ellipse,svg)
{
    var sCTM = ellipse.getCTM()
    var scaleX  = sCTM.a;
    var scaleY  = sCTM.d;

    var cx=parseFloat(ellipse.getAttribute("cx"))
    var cy=parseFloat(ellipse.getAttribute("cy"))

    var rx=parseFloat(ellipse.getAttribute("rx"))
    var ry=parseFloat(ellipse.getAttribute("ry"))

    var mySVGPointC = svg.createSVGPoint();
    mySVGPointC.x = cx
    mySVGPointC.y = cy
    mySVGPointTransC = mySVGPointC.matrixTransform(sCTM)
    ellipse.setAttribute("cx",mySVGPointTransC.x)
    ellipse.setAttribute("cy",mySVGPointTransC.y)

    ellipse.setAttribute("rx",rx*scaleX)
    ellipse.setAttribute("ry",ry*scaleY)

    //---force removal of transform--
    ellipse.setAttribute("transform","")
    ellipse.removeAttribute("transform")
}
function screenRect(rect,svg)
{
    var sCTM = rect.getCTM()
    var scaleX  = sCTM.a;
    var scaleY  = sCTM.d;

    var x=parseFloat(rect.getAttribute("x"))
    var y=parseFloat(rect.getAttribute("y"))

    var width=parseFloat(rect.getAttribute("width"))
    var height=parseFloat(rect.getAttribute("height"))

    var mySVGPoint = svg.createSVGPoint();
    mySVGPoint.x = x
    mySVGPoint.y = y
    mySVGPointTrans = mySVGPoint.matrixTransform(sCTM)
    rect.setAttribute("x",mySVGPointTrans.x)
    rect.setAttribute("y",mySVGPointTrans.y)

    rect.setAttribute("width",width*scaleX)
    rect.setAttribute("height",height*scaleY)

    //---force removal of transform--
    rect.setAttribute("transform","")
    rect.removeAttribute("transform")
}
function screenPolyline(myPoly,svg)
{
    var sCTM = myPoly.getCTM()
    var pointsList = myPoly.points;
    var n = pointsList.numberOfItems;
    for(var m=0;m<n;m++)
    {
        var mySVGPoint = mySVG.createSVGPoint();
        mySVGPoint.x = pointsList.getItem(m).x
        mySVGPoint.y = pointsList.getItem(m).y
        mySVGPointTrans = mySVGPoint.matrixTransform(sCTM)
        pointsList.getItem(m).x=mySVGPointTrans.x
        pointsList.getItem(m).y=mySVGPointTrans.y
    }
    //---force removal of transform--
    myPoly.setAttribute("transform","")
    myPoly.removeAttribute("transform")
}

function screenPath(path,svg)
{
    var sCTM = path.getCTM()
    var scaleX  = sCTM.a;
    var scaleY  = sCTM.d;

    var segList=path.pathSegList
    var segs=segList.numberOfItems
    //---change segObj values
    for(var k=0;k<segs;k++)
    {
        var segObj=segList.getItem(k)

        if(segObj.x && segObj.y )
        {
            var mySVGPoint = svg.createSVGPoint();
            mySVGPoint.x = segObj.x
            mySVGPoint.y = segObj.y
            mySVGPointTrans = mySVGPoint.matrixTransform(sCTM)
            segObj.x=mySVGPointTrans.x
            segObj.y=mySVGPointTrans.y
        }

        if(segObj.x1 && segObj.y1)
        {
            var mySVGPoint1 = svg.createSVGPoint();
            mySVGPoint1.x = segObj.x1
            mySVGPoint1.y = segObj.y1
            mySVGPointTrans1 = mySVGPoint1.matrixTransform(sCTM)
            segObj.x1=mySVGPointTrans1.x
            segObj.y1=mySVGPointTrans1.y
        }
        if(segObj.x2 && segObj.y2)
        {
            var mySVGPoint2 = svg.createSVGPoint();
            mySVGPoint2.x = segObj.x2
            mySVGPoint2.y = segObj.y2
            mySVGPointTrans2 = mySVGPoint2.matrixTransform(sCTM)
            segObj.x2=mySVGPointTrans2.x
            segObj.y2=mySVGPointTrans2.y
        }

        if(segObj.r1)segObj.r1=segObj.r1*scaleX
        if(segObj.r2)segObj.r2=segObj.r2*scaleX
    }
    //---force removal of transform--
    path.setAttribute("transform","")
    path.removeAttribute("transform")
}

//---changes all transformed points to screen points---
function screenPolygon(myPoly,mySVG)
{
    var sCTM = myPoly.getCTM()
    var pointsList = myPoly.points;
    var n = pointsList.numberOfItems;
    for(var m=0;m<n;m++)
    {
        var mySVGPoint = mySVG.createSVGPoint();
        mySVGPoint.x = pointsList.getItem(m).x
        mySVGPoint.y = pointsList.getItem(m).y
        mySVGPointTrans = mySVGPoint.matrixTransform(sCTM)
        pointsList.getItem(m).x=mySVGPointTrans.x
        pointsList.getItem(m).y=mySVGPointTrans.y
    }
    //---force removal of transform--
    myPoly.setAttribute("transform","")
    myPoly.removeAttribute("transform")
}
```